# slds-input css doesn't work

Tags: css, slds, lightninginput, style

Hello guys I have a doubt related with Lighning-input style.

I'm trying to align the value inside the textbox to the right but it seems that my css is ignored by Salesforce.

I have the following HTML:

```
<td data-label="NewPrice" key={addOnCharge}>
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="NewPrice" style='margin-left: 30%;'>
                            <lightning-input if:false={isSummaryScreen} type="text" disabled={addOn.isDisabled} value={addOnCharge.billableValue} access-key={addOn.id} class = 'slds-text-align_right' style='margin-bottom: 13px; width: 40%; display: inline-block; text-align: right;' name="inputNewPrice"  onchange={handlePriceChange}  label=""></lightning-input>
                            <div if:false={isSummaryScreen} class="currencyClass" style='display: inline-block; margin-left: 3%'>{currency}</div>
                            <div if:true={isSummaryScreen} class="slds-truncate outputNewPrice" style='color: rgb(46, 132, 74); font-weight: bold;' title="Current Price Value">{addOnCharge.billableValue} {currency}</div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </td>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.slds-input{
      text-align: right;
  }
```

for some reason this does not work, can somebody help me out, thanks

Comment: Are you attempting  this in a Digital Experience or in the normal desktop UI?

Comment: VS code and I deploy it with SFDX

I have the html file inside and a css one with the same name, standard LWC component